# Resolution Test chrome extension not working?

Tags: resolution, ubuntu-12.04, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

**Browser**: Chromium version 28.something
**OS**: Ubuntu 12.04

I tried Window resizer earlier and now resolution test. None of them worked. Whats the issue. Both the extensions have got 4.5 rating.

Is it because of ubuntu?

Comment: Is Chrome maximized?

Comment: of course! it is always maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't allow extensions to resize its window when it's maximized. Make sure it's not maximized and Resolution Test should work fine.